# Saving to user defaults on app load

Tags: load, save, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I've recently implemented a system of saving a number of arrays, boolean values and ints into the user defaults. Now i currently use three buttons on my interface to test the functionality out and it works correctly, however i am running into problems trying to automate the save system.

Essentially i want the app to save the data either when it terminates or when it is pushed to the background. It then only loads the data when the app is restarted fully.

I've tried using the folowing appdelegate delegate methods to run the methods i created to save and load:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
applicationWillTerminate:
```

But they don't seem to work, i know that i'll need the enter foreground method for saving when the app is pushed back, but presently nothing works. The app appears to crash or fails to save and load the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you post the question, at least add a tag like `iphone` or `objective c` or `ios`, so that all can get your question. ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should save your `defaults` in

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method.

And, for again accessing `defaults`, fetch data in

`- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`

or in

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`
 method.

Comment: I've tried this and am getting some odd results. The app seems to save the data when its minimised but then fails to load the data if the app is exited manually (fully by stopping the app process) and reloaded, secondly simply exiting the app as above fails to save the data. I'll do some proper checks, so i can break down whats going on and post my code, but any initial ideas?

Comment: Did Userdefaults saved data when you exited by pressing home button?? If yes, then again when you enter the app, `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called. And you can get the Defaults data from there...
Put `NSLog` when you exit, so that you can know whether it saves Defaults or not...

Comment: Thanks, worked correctly, i must have been half asleep when coding as i had the methods being called under the incorrect app delegate methods.